# Creating a Jquery slideshow animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slideshow

Im trying to create my own slideshow, 
i know there are alot of plugins avaible but there was nothing i could find that matched my needs.

The slideshow itself works, the problem i encounter is the animations.
when u click the next button multiple times everything gets messed up..

the .stop() nor the .clearQueue() function work because that makes the animation stop without finishing it first.

Source:
http://www.alphadesigns.nl/ADtest/JQ/js/portfolio.js

Preview:
http://www.alphadesigns.nl/ADtest/JQ/

any help is appreciated!

ps. the slideshow itsself isnt finished by a long shot, the "huge images" will be changed to smaller thumbnails etc. but i first want the animation to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your script it would appear you are running into a race condition. You are removing and adding classes faster than you think and thus creating a condition where you are selecting multiple items when you intended to only select one.

for example:

```
slidecontent = $('.slidecontent');
slideimg.prepend(slidecontent.children('img').addClass('slidecontent'));
slidecontent.removeClass('slidecontent').addClass('slideleft thisclassc');
```

In your `previmg` function you have the above lines. If you click the button that triggers this function too quickly you end up with more than one item in the object `slidecontent` because you assigned the same class to the next element in the list. You need to somehow lock out the function until it has completed or you need to make a more specific selector.

the easiest way I can think to do this but not the most elegant is to create a locking flag. You would then test the locking flag before the function ran in order to avoid a race condition **and set an instant timeout so that you return immediately and ignore the extra clicks**:

```
var animActive = false;

$.fn.previmg = function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if(totalrightimg != 0 && animActive==false){
            animactive = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                //everything else
                animactive = false;
            },0);
        }
        else if(totalrightimg == 0 && animActive==false){
            animactive = true;
            setTimeout(function(){
                //everything else
                animactive = false;
            },0);
        }
    }
});
```

if you add this variable and then make this check, you are going to be sure to avoid the race condition because you won't be running the manipulations on top of each other. Each time the manipulation runs, it locks out its ability to run again until it is done. So subsequent clicks would be ignored.

if this behavior is undesirable you would want to look into a way to narrow your selector of the '`slidecontent`' class so that you are ensuring you are only ever selecting one element.

EDIT: Totally ignored the synchronous handling of click events. My bad. The above code will force the locking and unlocking into separate scopes so you should be safe executing the change code.

Comment: I have been thinking about this solution myself, but i didnt know how to do it. turns out its really simple :P
Thanks alot! and a happy new year! :D

Comment: sometimes the hardest things to think of, are the easiest things to implement. I am glad it is going to work for you. Happy new year.

Comment: Im trying to use this trick, but still its not working correctly because it makes animactive = false, right after clicking.
im trying to add a delay, but its not working:
$.delay(2200,function(){animactive = false});
any ideas?

Comment: make sure the var animActive declaration and initial assignment are of global scope or are only initialized once. I did not see an initialize function for your script so your only option is to declare and assign the intitial value globally. Put var animActive = false; as the first line of your script before $(document).ready(). This way it is only declared and assigned a default value once.

Comment: the actually problem is that once i click i need to have a delay of 2200 miliseconds before i can click again. if i simply put animactive = false, inside the click function, then it will be false again right after the click, so it has nothing to do with declaring the value globally..

Comment: I see what you are saying. I changed my answer to reflect a different approach. You need to handle that code asynchronously. http://jsfiddle.net/bk7b5/1/ Check the console to see that the 'action' only happens every 2200 mili-seconds and all other clicks while that time is passing are ignored.

Comment: Thanks :) this is exactly what i ment :) again, happy new year and best wishes :)!

Comment: well first ill have to learn more about how to use the date function etc. because i started learning jQuery by making this slideshow :P but ill figure it out with the fiddle you created by playing around with it ;) cheers :)

Comment: i figured out how to do this the best way, your fiddle introduced me to the setTimeout function :) wich i used to help in my need.
http://jsfiddle.net/CqHxU/

thanks again for your help :)

Comment: just added it to the slideshow (y) this solved my issue :D
http://www.alphadesigns.nl/ADtest/JQ/